# Finding $\tan(x+90^\circ)$ when $\sin x = k$ and $x$ is obtuse. I get the reciprocal of the correct answer.

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

> If $\sin x = k$ and $x$ is obtuse, find an expression for $\tan(x+90^circ)$.

So $$\tan(x+90^\circ)=\frac{\sin(x+90^\circ)}{\cos(x+90^\circ)}$$
and after drawing a triangle, I obtain
$${\sin(x+90^\circ)} = -k \qquad\text{and}\qquad\cos(x+90^\circ)= -\sqrt{1-k^2}$$ because $x+90^\circ$ is in Quadrant 3 where both $\sin$ and $\cos$ are negative.

So $$\tan(x+90) = \frac{k}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}$$

However, the answer is the reciprocal of this. Why is that so?

Comment: $90+x$ is an angle in 2nd quadrant, isn't it?

Comment: @Bumblebee of course not; it is given that $x$ is obtuse.

Comment: Do you really believe $\sin(181^\circ) = -\sin(91^\circ)$?

Comment: @AndrewChin: Oh... I didn't see that.

Comment: $\sin(x+ 90) \ne -k$.  Draw a picture of an angle $x$ in the second quadrant.  Let $(\cos x, \sin y) = (-j,k)$ rotate the picture a quarter turn.  *DON'T* flip it on its axis.  Rotate a quarter turn.  Notice that the new coordinates are $(\cos(90 + k), \sin (90+k))$ are now $(-k, -j)$ and $\sin (90 + x) = -\cos x$ and $\cos (90+x)=-\sin x$.  So $\sin(x+90) = -\sqrt {1-k^2}$ and $\cos(x+90) =-k$.

Comment: Read this https://themathpage.com/aTrig/graphs-trig.htm about 2/3 of the way down when the discuss $\sin(x +\frac \pi 2)$.  And maybe this image helps https://themathpage.com/aTrig/TRIG_IMG/010.gif (although it is an image of an acute angle in quadrant 1 rotated to quadrant 2, not quad 2 to quad 3.  But the idea is the same).

Answer (score 1):

You should have identites that $\sin(x + 90) = \cos x$ and *not* $\sin(x+90) \ne -\sin x$. And that $\cos(x+ 90) =-\sin x$ and *not* $\cos (x+90) \ne \cos x$.

You can prove it by the $\sin(x+90) = \sin x\cos 90 + \cos x\sin 90$ and $\cos(x+90) = \sin x\cos 90 - \cos x \sin 90$.

But you should draw circles on graph paper and rotate it a quarter turn to convince yourself.

Comment: Oh ok - I only thought so it is known that $x$ is obtuse - therefore it must lie in the 3rd quadrant if you add $90$. Both sin and cos are negative there

Comment: The issue isn't whether they are positive or negative.  The issue is what *VALUE* they have.  If $\sin x = k$ then $\sin (x+90)$ is negative, but negative *what*?  It sure as cornflakes is *NOT* negative $k$.    And $\cos (x+90)$ is negative, but negative *what*? It sure as brownies is *NOT* negative $\sqrt{1 -k^2}$.  You aren't reflexting a circle across the $x$ axis which would be when $(-x, y) \to (-x, -y)$ occurs.  You are *ROTATING* it.  So $(-x, y) \to (-y, -x)$ occurs.

Comment: Suppose you took $(\sin 91, \cos 91)$ then point $(x,y) $ is just a tiny bit past $(0,1)$ so $\cos x = -something close to zero$ and $\sin x =+somethingclose to one$. No you rotate it $90$ degrees.  *NOW* $(x,y)$ is just a tiny bit past $(-1,0)$. So $\cos x = -something close to one$ and $\sin(x+90) = -something close to zero$.  So $\sin(90 + x) = \cos x$.  And $\cos(x+90) = -\sin x$.... As Eric Towers pointed in his comment: $\sin 91= some very close to one$. But $\sin 181 =something just slightly less thanzero$.  So $\sin(x+90)$ *DOESNT* equal $-\sin x$

Answer (score 0):

Given $\tan(x+90) = \frac{\sin(90+x)}{\\cos(90+x)}$,

$sin(+90)= sin(x)cos(90)+cos(x)sin(90)$=cos(x)
$cos(+90) =cos(x)cos(90)-sin(90)sin(x)$=-sin(x)

$\tan(x+90) = -\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$,

x in Quad II, cos(x) <0, $\sin(x)=k, \cos(x) = - \sqrt{1- k^2}$

$\tan(90+x) = \frac{\sqrt{1-k^2}}{k}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).